# Calculate sum & min from database tables all column

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code for calculate all numbers.  I have added price/number (10) in all table

```
$SQL = "SELECT p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 - p0 as total_price from table WHERE id = '1'";
```

This query works for me like, first sum all table p1=10 + p2=10 ..... result 40 minus p0=2 total price 38.

but I want to subtract p0 from all columns like

> "p1 = 10" - "p0 = 2" = 8
> "p2 = 10" - "p0 = 2" = 8
> "p3 = 10" - "p0 = 2" = 8
> "p4 = 10" - "p0 = 2" = 8
>
> and sum p1+p2+p3+p4 final result = 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `(p1 + p2 + p3 + p4) - 4 * p0`. Btw `4 * 8 = 32`

Comment: Thanks @nanodanger ! but when i remove price/number from (p4 or p3) or any column then this code showing wrong result. like 22 but i want to showing 24

Comment: @ImranHafeez: if you remove one of the columns, you have to decrease the number that you multiply p0 with. So if you only have (p1 + p2 + p3) - 3  * p0 then as you can see you only multiply it by 3.

Comment: actually this is a timing database. i have entered auto '0' sec in all column, p1,p2 is Person1, Person2, every person start time (23400 sec like 06:30:00), i wanna show every person working time a day. and end of all show all person working time a day. i have PHP code but i wanna calculate all time in sql Query